# How quick jump to specific lines in differents buffers?

Tags: motion, navigation

Linux Mint 21

Emacs 27.1

Suppose I open 3 different text files. As result open 3 differents buffers.

E.g.

```
text_1.txt
text_2.txt
text_3.txt
```

Is it possible to jump using keybinding to the next lines?

```
text_1.txt - line 100
text_2.txt - line 45
text_3.txt - line 589
```

So, e.g.

If I press `C-1` -> jump to text_1.txt line 100.

If I press `C-2` -> jump to text_2.txt line 45.

If I press `C-3` -> jump to text_3.txt line 580.

But later I want to remove this keybinding. And e.g bind `C-1` to another file `text_3.txt` and line number `200`.

So I need to bind and unbind.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to bind an entire key sequence just for the purpose of jumping to a **certain** line?

Comment: If you want to jump to a specific line immediately after opening a file, you can take a look at the command line argument `+linenum`.

Comment: You can write a command to do `(switch-to-buffer "text_1.txt) (goto-line 100)` and bind it to a key, but as @shynur says, it's a waste: you have a keybinding that does this very specific thing. And keybindings are a scarce resource.

Comment: @shynur I was updated my post

Comment: Can't you just use bookmarks? I use C-M-a a for bookmark-set and C-M-a l for bookmark-bmenu-list. For quick jumps, I use F7 (detour-mark) and F9 (detour-back), but I always find that I need more detours. I also use registers extensively to jump between files, but not dynamically (C-x r j). I have common files that I always use in registers.

Comment: "Is it possible?" - of course, it's possible, but it's a pain (and you don't want to use `C-1` etc for the keybindings - those have specific meaning in Emacs and you should probably not change that - see [Key Binding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html)). There are better methods to remember places in files. @JasonHunter mentions bookmarks and registers, but there are also links (e.g. you can maintain a list of links in an Org mode file - something like `[[file:~/.config/emacs/init.el::100][l.100 of my init.el]]` ).